# How do I install a plugin for vim?

Tags: vim

I'd like to try the plugin for Vim linked below. It adds syntax highlighting for `.haml` and (perhaps) `.sass` files.

http://github.com/tpope/vim-haml

I did this...

```
$ cd ~/.vim
$ git clone git://github.com/tpope/vim-haml.git
```

I opened a `.haml` file in Vim, but there's no highlighting. There must be another step I need to perform.

Comment: G'day, Is syntax switched on? (To ask the obvious)

Comment: I'm new to Vim. How do I switch syntax on?

Comment: @ethan in normal mode, `:syntax on`

Comment: good answer here http://superuser.com/questions/404686/installing-plugins-in-vim

Comment: Perfect question for the new Vim QA: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/76728/vi-vim?referrer=OrIobLykDezijasUR37EQA2

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Those two commands will create a `~/.vim/vim-haml/` directory with the ftplugin, syntax, etc directories in it. Those directories need to be immediately in the `~/.vim` directory proper or `~/.vim/vim-haml` needs to be added to the list of paths that vim searches for plugins.

**Edit:**

I recently decided to tweak my vim config and in the process wound up writing the following rakefile. It only works on Mac/Linux, but the advantage over `cp` versions is that it's completely safe (symlinks don't overwrite existing files, uninstall only deletes symlinks) and easy to keep things updated.

```rb
# Easily install vim plugins from a source control checkout (e.g. Github)
#
# alias vim-install=rake -f ~/.vim/rakefile-vim-install
# vim-install
# vim-install uninstall

require 'ftools'
require 'fileutils'

task :default => :install
desc "Install a vim plugin the lazy way"
task :install do
  vim_dir      = File.expand_path("~/.vim")
  plugin_dir   = Dir.pwd

  if not (FileTest.exists? File.join(plugin_dir,".git") or
          FileTest.exists? File.join(plugin_dir,".svn") or
          FileTest.exists? File.join(plugin_dir,".hg"))
      puts "#{plugin_dir} isn't a source controlled directory. Aborting."
      exit 1
  end

  Dir['**/'].each do |d|
    FileUtils.mkdir_p File.join(vim_dir, d)
  end

  Dir["**/*.{txt,snippet,snippets,vim,js,wsf}"].each do |f|
    ln File.join(plugin_dir, f), File.join(vim_dir,f)
  end

  boldred = "\033[1;31m"
  clear = "\033[0m"
  puts "\nDone. Remember to #{boldred}:helptags ~/.vim/doc#{clear}"
end

task :uninstall do
  vim_dir      = File.expand_path("~/.vim")
  plugin_dir   = Dir.pwd
  Dir["**/*.{txt,snippet,snippets,vim}"].each do |f|
    safe_rm File.join(vim_dir, f)
  end
end

def nicename(path)
    boldgreen = "\033[1;32m"
    clear = "\033[0m"
    return "#{boldgreen}#{File.join(path.split('/')[-2..-1])}#{clear}\t"
end

def ln(src, dst)
    begin
        FileUtils.ln_s src, dst
        puts "    Symlink #{nicename src}\t => #{nicename dst}"
    rescue Errno::EEXIST
        puts "  #{nicename dst} exists! Skipping."
    end
end

def cp(src, dst)
  puts "    Copying #{nicename src}\t=> #{nicename dst}"
  FileUtils.cp src, dst
end

def safe_rm(target)
    if FileTest.exists? target and FileTest.symlink? target
        puts "    #{nicename target} removed."
        File.delete target
    else
        puts "  #{nicename target} is not a symlink. Skipping"
    end
end
```

Answer (score 132):

Make sure that the actual `.vim` file is in `~/.vim/plugin/`

Comment: Yes, I guess this one solves most of users' questions.

Comment: Or in any subdirectory under ~/.vim/plugin/?

Comment: To be clear: when you say `~/.vim`, you mean wherever vim is installed, right? The place stored in `$VIM` (i.e. if you `:echom $VIM`, that's the place)

Comment: @QPaysTaxes on my system `:echom $VIM` shows `/usr/share/vim`. But this answer uses the prefix `~`  to suggests installing plugins in the user's home directory.

Answer (score 45):

To expand on Karl's reply, Vim looks in a specific set of directories for its runtime files.  You can see that set of directories via `:set runtimepath?`.  In order to tell Vim to also look inside `~/.vim/vim-haml` you'll want to add

```
set runtimepath+=$HOME/.vim/vim-haml
```

to your `~/.vimrc`.  You'll likely also want the following in your `~/.vimrc` to enable all the functionality provided by vim-haml.

```
filetype plugin indent on
syntax on
```

You can refer to the [`'runtimepath'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27runtimepath%27) and [`:filetype`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/filetype.txt.html#%3Afiletype) help topics in Vim for more information.

Comment: Is is "syntax on" or ":syntax on"? Likewise with "filetype"/":filtype".

Comment: When you type them interactively, you need the ':' to enter cmdline mode.  In a script, they aren't needed because the script is in cmdline mode, so to speak.  Because of that, it's standard practice to omit the ':'s in scripts as all it does is add unnecessary clutter.

Answer (score 19):

I think you should have a look at the [Pathogen plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2332). After you have this installed, you can keep all of your plugins in separate folders in ~/.vim/bundle/, and Pathogen will take care of loading them.

Or, alternatively, perhaps you would prefer [Vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/vundle), which provides similar functionality (with the added bonus of automatic updates from plugins in github).

Answer (score 3):

Update (as 2019):

```sh
cd ~/.vim
git clone git://github.com/tpope/vim-haml.git pack/bundle/start/haml
```

**Explanation** (from `:h pack` ad `:h packages`):

1. All the directories found are added to `runtimepath`. They must be in ~/.vim/**pack**/whatever/**start** [you can only change whatever].
2. the plugins found in the `plugins` dir in `runtimepath` are sourced.

So this load the plugin on start (hence the name start).

You can also get optional plugin (loaded with `:packadd`) if you put them in ~/.vim/**pack**/bundle/**opt**

Comment: Detailed explanations would go a long way, but this is my preferred method, so have an upvote